# Using numbers in a text file, in an equation

Tags: python

So here is my dilemma, I need to use a file that contains:

```
0.01
0.005
0.0001
0.1
```

I need to pull these numbers out, assign them to separate variables and then use those in an  equation.

Could anyone explain how to do this? Problems I am running into include, converting them to floats, pulling them out of the list without the "\n" character and then actually getting them to work in an equation. Any help appreciated.

Comment: show us your code written so far please

Comment: downvote for write-code-for-me

Answer (score 2):

```
filename = 'numbers.txt'
with open(filename,'r') as the_file:
    num_list = [float(line) for line in the_file]
```

Now you have `num_list` containing all the float numbers.

Is that what you want?

If you have exactly four numbers, you can use this:

```
[var1, var2, var3, var4] = [float(line) for line in the_file]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is literally just four lines (as you describe) you can do:

```
def conv(s):
    try:
        rtr=float(s)
    except ValueError:
        rtr=s
    return rtr        

with open('/tmp/floats.txt', 'r') as fin:
    v1,v2,v3,v4=[conv(s) for s in fin]
```